# SQL Trigger After Update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that will show how many records were loaded and the first date and last date the records were loaded at

Also I need to determine that if the same records were updated track the information as well

The output I'm looking for is something like this:

```
tablename   recordcount mindate             maxdate               operation
customer    5000        2019/12/10 12:00    2019/12/10 12:15      INSERT
tablename   recordcount mindate             maxdate               operation
customer    2500        2019/12/10 12:20    2019/12/10 12:25      UPDATE
```

This is the code I have used

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[utr_customer]
ON [dbo].[customer]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN 

    IF UPDATE([Address])
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[TrackDataLoad](TableName,RecordCount,FirstRecord_LoadDate,LastRecord_LoadDate,[Operation])
        SELECT
            '[dbo].[customer]' AS TableName,
            COUNT(*) AS RecordCount,
            MIN(CreatedDate) AS FirstRecord_LoadDate,
            MAX(CreatedDate) AS LastRecord_LoadDate,
            'UPDT' AS [Operation],
        FROM inserted
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[TrackDataLoad](TableName,RecordCount,FirstRecord_LoadDate,LastRecord_LoadDate,[Operation])
        SELECT
            '[dbo].[customer]' AS TableName,
            COUNT(*) AS RecordCount,
            MIN(CreatedDate) AS FirstRecord_LoadDate,
            MAX(CreatedDate) AS LastRecord_LoadDate,
            'INS' AS [Operation],
        FROM inserted
    END
END
```

Will this code work for the desired output?

Because I tested it out and I got this result set:

```
tablename   recordcount mindate             maxdate             operation
customer    1           2019/12/10 12:00    2019/12/10 12:00    INSERT
customer    1           2019/12/10 12:01    2019/12/10 12:01    INSERT
customer    1           2019/12/10 12:02    2019/12/10 12:02    INSERT
customer    1           2019/12/10 12:03    2019/12/10 12:03    INSERT
customer    1           2019/12/10 12:04    2019/12/10 12:04    INSERT
customer    1           2019/12/10 12:05    2019/12/10 12:05    INSERT
customer    1           2019/12/10 12:06    2019/12/10 12:06    INSERT
customer    1           2019/12/10 12:07    2019/12/10 12:07    INSERT
customer    1           2019/12/10 12:08    2019/12/10 12:08    INSERT
```

Comment: how are you inserting the rows into the table?

Comment: so usually what happens that a SQL job from another table from another server load records into the table,i hope that helps

Comment: What means `load records into the table` - does it insert them one by one or all records once? BTW, your queries need `group by` and your output doesn't match queries anyway (different strings).

Comment: i have tried the group by and it does not work, and it is loading records one at a time, hope this helps